# Python Convert Excel to CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, character-encoding, file-conversion

Seems there are a lot of posts on this subject and my solution is in line with what the most common answer seems to be, however I'm encountering an encoding error that I don't know how to address.

```
>>> def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
     import xlrd
     import csv
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
     worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
     csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
     wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
         wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))

     csvfile.close()

>>> Excel2CSV(r"C:\Temp\Store List.xls", "Open_Locations", 
              r"C:\Temp\StoreList.csv")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
Excel2CSV(r"C:\Temp\Store List.xls", "Open_Locations", r"C:\Temp\StoreList.csv")
File "<pyshell#1>", line 10, in Excel2CSV
wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 14:
ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @davidism points out, the Python 2 `csv` module doesn't work with unicode. You can work around this by converting all of your `unicode` objects to `str` objects before submitting them to `csv`:

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
     import xlrd
     import csv
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
     worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
     csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
     wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
         wr.writerow(
             list(x.encode('utf-8') if type(x) == type(u'') else x
                  for x in worksheet.row_values(rownum)))

     csvfile.close()
```

Comment: In Python3 (after updating the range), I get this error: 
**TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: this tripped me up as well for a minute.  The line `csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')` should read `csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'w')`.  It's one of the annoying little 2 - 3 translations.

Answer (score 2):

The Python 2 `csv` module has some problems with unicode data.  You can either encode everything to UTF-8 before writing, or use the [`unicodecsv`](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) module to do it for you.

First `pip install unicodecsv`.  Then, instead of `import csv`, just `import unicodecsv as csv`.  The API is the same (plus encoding options), so no other changes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another fashion for doing this: cast to string, so as you have a string, you may codify it as "utf-8".

```
str(worksheet.row_values(rownum)).encode('utf-8')
```

The whole function:

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
     import xlrd
     import csv
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
     worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
     csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
     wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
         wr.writerow(str(worksheet.row_values(rownum)).encode('utf-8'))

     csvfile.close()
```